# what does "$&" mean in Ruby

Tags: ruby, syntax, global-variables

I notice one line code in spree library:

```
label_with_first_letters_capitalized = t(options[:label]).gsub(/\b\w/)#{$&.upcase}
```

could someone tell me what does "$&" mean ? thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a [reference to some of those special variables allowed in ruby](https://web.archive.org/web/20110702055137/http://jimneath.org/2010/01/04/cryptic-ruby-global-variables-and-their-meanings.html). Basically, this one returns whatever the last pattern match was.

From linked page:

> `$&` contains the matched string from the previous successful pattern match.
>
> ```
> >> "the quick brown fox".match(/quick.*fox/)
> => #<MatchData:0x129cc40>
> >> $&
> => "quick brown fox"
> ```

Comment: This link is bad

Comment: @drharris: could also also include the relevant part of the page in the answer directly?

Answer (score 4):

In my testing, it appears to be the last match that `gsub` got. So for instance, if I have this:

```
"Hello, world!".gsub(/o./, "a")
```

`$&` would be set to `or`, because that is the last match that `gsub` encountered.

Answer (score 2):

`$&` is the string that was matched by the last successful regex.  For example:

```
foobar = "foobar"
regex = /b.{2}/

if regex.match(foobar) then
    puts $&    # -> bar
end
```